# Parse csv file by using Spring Batch and print it on console in spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

My goal of the Project :

I have to read csv file by using Spring Batch and extract the specific column information like (Column Name :"msdin") "msdin" can print it on console. But my application is showing failed to start the application.

Well it is asking me to configure the data Source.Why we need to configure the data source in case of spring batch if my requirement is to read the csv file and print it on console.

I tried to identify the issues but not able to resolve. Can anybody help me how to resolve this issues?

## Domain Class

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private Long id_type;
    private String id_number;
    private String customer_name;
    private String email_address;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private String citizenship;
    private String address;
    private Long msisdn;
    private LocalDate kyc_date;
    private String kyc_level;
    private String goalscore;
    private String mobile_network;

    public Long getId_type() {
        return id_type;
    }

    public void setId_type(Long id_type) {
        this.id_type = id_type;
    }

    public String getId_number() {
        return id_number;
    }

    public void setId_number(String id_number) {
        this.id_number = id_number;
    }

    public String getCustomer_name() {
        return customer_name;
    }

    public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name) {
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
    }

    public String getEmail_address() {
        return email_address;
    }

    public void setEmail_address(String email_address) {
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getCitizenship() {
        return citizenship;
    }

    public void setCitizenship(String citizenship) {
        this.citizenship = citizenship;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Long getMsisdn() {
        return msisdn;
    }

    public void setMsisdn(Long msisdn) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
    }

    public LocalDate getKyc_date() {
        return kyc_date;
    }

    public void setKyc_date(LocalDate kyc_date) {
        this.kyc_date = kyc_date;
    }

    public String getKyc_level() {
        return kyc_level;
    }

    public void setKyc_level(String kyc_level) {
        this.kyc_level = kyc_level;
    }

    public String getGoalscore() {
        return goalscore;
    }

    public void setGoalscore(String goalscore) {
        this.goalscore = goalscore;
    }

    public String getMobile_network() {
        return mobile_network;
    }

    public void setMobile_network(String mobile_network) {
        this.mobile_network = mobile_network;
    }
}
```

## BatchConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Value("classPath:/data/gcash.csv")
    private Resource inputResource;

    public ItemReader<Customer> itemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        customerItemReader.setLineMapper(linemapper());
        customerItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        customerItemReader.setResource(inputResource);
        return customerItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<Customer> linemapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<Customer> linemapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        final DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter(";");
        tokenizer.setStrict(false);
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "id_type", "id_number", "customer_name", "email_address", "birthday",
                "citizenship", "address", "msisdn", "kyc_date", "kyc_level", "goalscore", "mobile_network" });
        linemapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Customer>() {
            {
                setTargetType(Customer.class);
            }
        });

        return linemapper;

    }
}
```

## Error Stack

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-04-27 11:05:46.235 ERROR 22368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gcash.milo</groupId>
    <artifactId>GCash_Milo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GCash_Milo</name>
    <description>Developing Milo project for GCash banking application.
    </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can you also add your pom.xml, spring boot  auto configures application based on dependencies

Comment: Have added the pom.xml. Please have a look.

Comment: remove the dependency of H2, if you don't need it . don't put it in pom

Comment: You have h2 in your classpath, so Spring Boot should configure an embedded datasource for you. Where is your main class located? Are you following the recommended structure: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code ? Please share a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

in your spring boot application class, add the following snippet to @SpringBootApplication annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

@SpringBootApplcation annotation uses @EnableAutoConfiguration, which expects a datasource to be configured

Comment: Can you guide  me how to print the parse csv file data to console?

Comment: this is what I answered! if you need further help, please locate the spring boot application class and share its code in your question. If you dont know where the application class is, then expand the folder structure and share the screenshot on your question.